# Geofencing with NO INTERNET conection?

Tags: notifications, gps, offline, geofencing

Is it possible to make an app that when closed and with no internet/data connection, if user enter a concrete area (detected with GPS), app send a notification? (sound + show message "push-like"?)

I thought yes it was possible, but then I saw that: https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/What-is-Geofencing-and-How-Geofencing-works.html

Not sure, but it seems it is not possible?? (they are talking about android, but what about iOS?)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It depends on what are your requirements, and mainly what it is your definition of "geofencing" (like many words, many people use it differently). You can do an app which check regularly the coordinates (no problem). Then you can make it running all time (backgound app: much more problems because every phone has own settings, and often they do not allow permission set by apps, because battery and abuse).

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
"Geofencing", well yes, can be a lot of things. I mean an app for a natural tour where there is no internet in a lot of areas. The idea is that the mobile send a notification when entering several areas, to show some content. 
The notification could be like a push?

I don't understand too much the fact that some devices don't allow at all permission.. Any idea if there are a lot of device like this? Maybe just a small proportion?
Because just for this reason, it seems my prroject is not possible.

Comment: yup, sounds doable.  e.g. most "GPS navigation" apps work off-line after they've planned the route and some have the map stored on the device so don't need to talk to any server.  android apps can trigger notifications if they're running in the background.  you'd need to get permissions from the user, and make sure all the data is available on the device before you expect it to lose the network connection, but that's normally easier than UI/UX issues

Comment: I have no idea on permissions. Some apps have more problems then others (especially some GPS trackers). But the work around in your case may be just a short wake up every few minutes (that should not cause much problems: the problem AFAIK is continuous running of background process [which may requires not just usual permission question, but also going in the settings and allowing the app to "have full battery power"). Note: GPS may be very wrong at every wakeup, without internet. so you may need to wait some time after a fix. In any caseI like your idea.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for your answers, it helped me a lot :)